# Story about someone that was large due to a disease, that uses VR

Tags: story-identification, books

This book was about this huge guy, who because of a disease was huge. He was going to die from this disease, but he was put to sleep and woke up in a VR MMO, and he is helped by his aunt. He then joins a group, and they level together. They then go on a quest that leads to the guy getting sacrificed. He doesn't die though, if I can remember correctly, because of his brute strength. This would’ve been a few years ago, maybe 3-5.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Might this be *[Nova Terra](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/43097346-nova-terra)* by Seth Ring?

[image: Front cover of Nova Terra: Titan]

> Trapped in his own body by a debilitating medical condition, Xavier Lee seeks reprieve from his giant-sized problems through full immersion into the game world of Nova Terra. Billed as the first true alternate reality, Nova Terra runs parallel to the real world and promises to fulfill the fantasies and desires of those who dare plunge into its mysterious depths. In order to adjust to his new life of quests, skill mastery, and magic, Xavier will have to forget everything he knows. As he struggles to make the most of his new-found freedom, Xavier will have to learn to deal with a new body, new friends, and a new world that is much more than it seems.

[This review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R2KOF9I4D59FVY/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B07L3DJNF5) mentions the aunt:

> It has been said in a prior review. When you are betrayed you don't just let it go... not to the extent it happens within this book, you don't just let it go. Add to the fact that you have the means to make them pay readily available in RL just makes this books ending very, very, weak and unrealistic. And that goes for the whole team, not just the leader. I am on the fence about continuing this series if the MC continues to be a door mat and doesn't use the resources at his disposal (his aunts extensive experience) to educate himself about the game.

Found with a search for `novel gigantism "virtual reality"`

Comment: Thank you so much! Have a great weekend!

Comment: How in the world are you guys able to find this so quickly? I’ve spent weeks on other forums trying to find it!

Comment: @SageBoy: Practice. Also a fair amount of luck, but I've gotten pretty good at figuring out ways to refine searched. Your mention of the growth disorder made me think of gigantism, which helped in picking out search terms.

Comment: And welcome to the site! I hope you stick around. We're a friendly sort.